# Should I remove these vines?

Tags: identification, trees, plant-health, tree-care, vines

Just closed on a home recently and am wondering if this tree is healthy? Should I remove these vines? Any tips on what these vines are and how to properly go about removing them?

Also if anyone knows what type of tree this might be?

Thank you, appreciate the help!

[image: Tree with Vines]

Comment: Where is the tree located?  what part of the world?

Comment: It looks like a [stem succulent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stem_succulent), which means it might be a cactus, Euphorbia, Stapelia or Hoodia. A close-up photo of one of the green stems would be helpful. If it has any flowers, fruit or seeds, a photo of those would let us figure out exactly what it is. Is the sap milky or clear? (If the sap is milky, be sure to wash it off your hands immediately because it may be toxic or cause skin irritation.)

Comment: Are they deliberately planted dragonfruit? [Wikipedia article - *Selenicereus undatus*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylocereus_undatus).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the vines. Here  (zone 8 , E TX) we have "strangler" vine that can kill branches and trees. And many other vines that do not . Some will get enough foliage to weaken a tree. Your vines are not stranglers but the photo does not show what is happening high in the tree.